# Вызов DLL из программы

Tags: c#, dll

Совсем не знаю как работать с DLL, хочу научиться хотя бы основам. Вот написал код, а как его вызвать из WindowsForms-приложения не знаю.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassMsg
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Msg() 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Подключаете к вашей программе ClassMsg.dll
Затем пишете в своей программе.
var class  = new Class1())
class.Msg();

Comment: Попробую завтра!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using "Пространство сборки"; // без кавычек

namespace DLLER
{
    class Class
    {
       public static void Main()
       {
          "Пространство сборки"."Имя класса" proc = new "Имя класса";
          proc."имя ф-ции в классе"();
       }
    }
}
```

"Пространство сборки" указываешь если не использовал using.

Comment: Спасибо робит урааааааааааа